# Having to recreate ObjectOutputStream every time

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I have seen a few people ask similar questions but the only answer anyone ever posts is that you shouldn't have to do it.

But I've tested it both ways - and it only works this way.

Server Side

```
    try {
        // Obtain input and output streams to the client
        while(true) {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            Object input = in.readObject();
            if(input == RequestEnums.GETCURRENTGRID) {
                out.writeObject(ContagionServerData.getImagePixels());
                out.writeObject(ContagionServerData.getImageHeight());
                out.writeObject(ContagionServerData.getImageWidth());
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Client Side

```
    try {
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeObject(RequestEnums.GETCURRENTGRID);
        int[] imagePixels = (int[]) inputStream.readObject();
        int imageHeight = (Integer) inputStream.readObject();
        int imageWidth = (Integer) inputStream.readObject();
        copyImage(background, imagePixels, imageHeight, imageWidth);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works all day long.

But if I change it to this -

```
    try {
        // Obtain input and output streams to the client
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while(true) {
            Object input = in.readObject();
            if(input == RequestEnums.GETCURRENTGRID) {
                out.writeObject(ContagionServerData.getImagePixels());
                out.writeObject(ContagionServerData.getImageHeight());
                out.writeObject(ContagionServerData.getImageWidth());
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(I have created the input and output stream farther up in the code)

```
    try {
        outputStream.writeObject(RequestEnums.GETCURRENTGRID);
        outputStream.flush();
        int[] imagePixels = (int[]) inputStream.readObject();
        int imageHeight = (Integer) inputStream.readObject();
        int imageWidth = (Integer) inputStream.readObject();
        copyImage(background, imagePixels, imageHeight, imageWidth);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then I successfully receive the correct data the first time from the server - but everytime after that - I just receive the same data and not the updated data and no errors as to why.

Comment: keeping long lasting ObjectOutputStream prevents any objects written to be GC'd until calling `reset()`. Calling `reset()` offers no significant benefits compared to re-creating the stream, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send data on an object stream, it will send each object only once. This means if you modify and object and send it multiple times, you need to either use `writeUnshared(mutableObject)` or `reset()` which clears the cache of objects already sent.

---

You can't create an ObjectOutput/InputStream repeatly.  If you want to make sure data is sent instead of buffered use `flush()`. If you are sending data like `int` instead of Objects, try DataOutput/InputStream.

Comment: I can create ObjectOutput/InputStreams repeatedly - like I said doing it that way works as far as data being transferred but its very slow.

I have also tried putting flush after anytime I write to the ObjectOutputStream in both the client and the server and it still doesn't work unless I recreate the input/output stream each time.

I am sending many types of data so I can't just restrict it to int.

Comment: @GeoffSmith he clearly stated to execute a flush command on the data stream so that you get the correct data each time

Comment: I updated my code about to reflect adding the flush command - and it is still not working as shown.

Comment: @GeoffSmith I have updated my answer as you appear to be sending a mutable object.

Comment: awesome Peter! Thank you so much - I've been looking for this answer for awhile now and it works perfectly =)

Answer (score 0):

See the Javadoc for `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` and `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared().`